# Close all children windows browser from another window

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts

This is my scenario:
I've a tab in my browser (IE8) and if I click on a link, I open a new window (window's name: "**Win2**").
Now, i came back to the first window, open a new tab in my browser, go to another page and click to a different link.
Once click on the last link, I want to close the page "**Win2**".
Can I do it with Javascript? How I can acces to the 1st-page's children from another page? 
Backend-side, I use Java 1.5 with framework struts.

Comment: From the same domain `window.open("","Win2").close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the return value of every call to window.open:

```
var windows = {};

windows.Win2 = window.open("...", "Win2");
```

To close all of them:

```
for (var name in windows) {
    if (windows.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        windows[name].close();
        windows[name] = null;
    }
}
```

Or to close one:

```
windows.Win2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the opened window in a variable in your parent window.

```
var Win2 = window.open("", "Win2");
```

Then you can close it later on using the variable.

```
Win2.close();
```

If you want to close Win2 from a different child window of the original parent. Create a function on your parent window, then call it from the child.

**Parent Window**

```
function CloseWin2() {
    Win2.close();
}
```

**Child Window**

```
if(window.opener) {
    window.opener.CloseWin2();
}
```